# Add Flutter functionality as a dependency in android library

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-platform-channel

##### Why do I need this?

I'm creating a Flutter package (for android) and I want to create the `MethodCallHandler`'s code in a separate AAR file that can be added in my plugin's code

So I'll have:

- `pluginNativeCode/android/MyPlugin.kt`

```kotlin
import ir.malv.android.flutter.MySeparateMethodCallHandler

class MyFlutterPlugin: FlutterPlugin {
   override fun onAttachedToEngine(...) {
      // Here's the source of the problem
      channel.setMethodCallHandler(MySeparateMethodCallHandler()) 
   }
}
```

The `MySeparateMethodCallHandler` is not in the `plugin/android` part and it's imported as a **gradle dependency**

**However in that library I don't have access to flutter's codes like `MethodCallHandler` class.**

##### Similar behaviour in unity and react native

> In react-native there is `com.facebook.react:react-native:+` that can be added as `compileOnly` to get the needed react-native codes

> In unity we have `unity.jar` file which contains unity native codes and can be added as `compileOnly` as well to provide engine's native APIs

**What do we have in Flutter for this?**

Is there a dependency that I can include as compileOnly and use it to get the needed classes and create my `aar` file in a separate project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

1. Add this remote to `repositories` of `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    // .. rest of remote urls

    maven { url("http://download.flutter.io/")}
  }
}
```

2. Add this dependency to module's `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  
  compileOnly("io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-0fdb562ac8068ce3dda6b69aca3f355f4d1d2718")

  // rest
}
```

Notice the `compileOnly`. This will avoid the class duplication. Plugin just requires it. The flutter app will provide it itself.

> **What is `0fdb562ac8068ce3dda6b69aca3f355f4d1d2718`**? 
>  It's the engine version that is good to match the version you are developing the plugin with.

in your code you will have access to needed classes such as `MethodChannel`, `MethodChannel.Result` and ...

---

**Bonus**: How do I know what engine I'm making the plugin with?

I think it should not matter if you just need a class like `MethodChannel` to invoke a method, but here's a way to get it using Android Studio

- Open the `project/example/android` of your plugin using **Android studio** (that has Flutter plugin activated)
- run `gradle plugin_name:dependencies` task and look for `flutter_embedding_` phrase.

Comment: Gosh, thank you so much for that one. Just one more addition: remember to set `allowInsecureProtocol = true` if Gradle complains that it doesn't allow HTTP over HTTPS.

Comment: @sunderee Good point. Feel free to edit the answer

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv I want to integrate flutter package into native android project . How can i do that?